# How to update data in Flutter Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i was trying to update data in Flutter Firebase

```
class DatabaseServices {


static FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
static CollectionReference datadokter = firestore.collection('data_dokter');

static Future<void> rankdokter(String? id) async {
    await datadokter.doc(id).update(
      {
        'rank': int.tryParse('rank')! + 1,
      },
    );
  }
}
```

but when i called this

```
DatabaseServices.rankdokter(id);
```

it still not update data 'rank' into +1
it means, its not increase.

anyone who can help me here ?

Comment: basically `int.tryParse('rank')` is gonna return you `null`, cause you're just trying to parse string to an int. `'rank'` is a string and not a value of your desired field

Answer (score 2):

simple use FieldValue.increment(1)

```
static Future<void> rankdokter(String? id) async {
    await datadokter.doc(id).update(
      {
        'rank': FieldValue.increment(1),
      },
    );
  }
```